# Going from a list to a data frame keeping the column name

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
[[29]]
                type              lineNum                  cat                  sel 
                 "I"                 "25"                "DOR"               "MN-A" 
                 act                 desc          descChanged                 calc 
                 "+" "Door labor minimum"                  "1"                  "1" 
                 qty                 unit         coverageName              replace 
                 "1"                 "EA"           "Dwelling"              "58.58" 
               total                  acv          recoverable             acvTotal 
             "58.58"              "58.58"                  "1"              "58.58" 
            rcvTotal   isPartOfInitSettle           laborTotal            laborBase 
             "58.58"                  "0"              "58.58"              "58.58" 

[[30]]
                  type                lineNum                    cat                    sel 
                   "I"                   "26"                  "WDW"                 "MN-A" 
                   act                   desc            descChanged                   calc 
                   "+" "Window labor minimum"                    "1"                    "1" 
                   qty                   unit           coverageName                replace 
                   "1"                   "EA"             "Dwelling"                 "69.5" 
                 total                    acv            recoverable               acvTotal 
                "69.5"                 "69.5"                    "1"                 "69.5" 
              rcvTotal     isPartOfInitSettle                          laborBase 
                "69.5"                    "0"                                 "69.5"
```

Here is a sample of my data.The number of columns are not the same. I am trying to create a data frame from this. I essentially want two rows here and match up by the column name.

I tried using plyr but it doesn't work as the number of columns is not the same.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst, as.list))`  If the number of columns are not the same, use `bind_rows` i.e. `purrr::map_df(lst, as.list)`

Comment: is you item a dataframe? or just vectors? if data.frames then `plyr::rbind.fill(lst)` will do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that

```
plyr::ldply(Item_list, rbind)
```

does the job

Answer (score 3):

We could use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_df(lst, as.list)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#      A     B     C     D     E
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3    NA    NA
#2     1     2    NA    NA    NA
#3     1     2     3     4     5
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(setNames(1:3, LETTERS[1:3]), setNames(1:2, LETTERS[1:2]), 
            setNames(1:5, LETTERS[1:5]))
```